# Upload image to server from camera/album - Corona sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I have a little problem related to uploading an image to server taken with the camera or from the photo album. I am using the following code to upload the image to my server: But with this code my server only recive the table value of the image like so: table: `0x11791daf0` , how can I get it to upload the image instead of the value? and would it also be possible to upload text with this code?

and the PHP script on my server in the end.

Thank you in advance :)

```
    local function monitorMem(event)
      collectgarbage("collect")

      print( "\nMemUsage: " .. (collectgarbage("count")/1000) .. " MB")
      print("Texture Usage " .. system.getInfo( "textureMemoryUsed" ) / 1000000)

      return true
    end

    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", monitorMem)




    local image 


    local mime = require "mime"

    local bkgd = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    bkgd:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )

    local myRoundedRect = display.newRoundedRect(10, 50, 80, 50, 12)
    myRoundedRect.strokeWidth = 3
    myRoundedRect:setFillColor(140, 140, 140)
    myRoundedRect:setStrokeColor(180, 180, 180)

    local sessionComplete = function(event) 
            image = event.target

            print( "Camera ", ( image and "returned an image" ) or "session was cancelled" )
            print( "event name: " .. event.name )
            print( "target: " .. tostring( image ) )

            if image then
                    -- center image on screen

                    image.x = display.contentWidth/2
                    image.y = 59
                    local w = image.width
                    local h = image.height
                    image.xScale = 0.3
                    image.yScale = 0.3
                    print( "w,h = ".. w .."," .. h )
            end
    end

    local listener = function( event )
            if media.hasSource( media.Camera ) then
                    media.show( media.Camera, sessionComplete )
            else
                    native.showAlert("Corona", "Camera not found.")
            end
            return true
    end
    myRoundedRect:addEventListener( "tap", listener )


    local myRoundedRect1 = display.newRoundedRect(10, 400, 150, 50, 12)
    myRoundedRect1.strokeWidth = 3
    myRoundedRect1:setFillColor(140, 140, 140)
    myRoundedRect1:setStrokeColor(180, 180, 180)

    local Name = "Imagename"


    function uploadBinary ( filename, url, onComplete )

           -- local path = system.pathForFile( filename )
           -- local fileHandle = io.open( path, "rb" ) 
           -- if fileHandle then 

           if image then

                         local params = {
                                        body = "image_file=" .. mime.b64(tostring( image )) .. "&image_filename="..Name
                            }


               --    io.close( fileHandle )

                    local function networkListener ( event )
                            if (onComplete) then
                                            onComplete(event);
                            end
                            return true;
                    end

                    network.request( url, "POST", networkListener,  params)
            end
    end

    local function networkListener( event )
            if ( event.isError ) then
                    print( "Network error!")
            else
                  --  print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response)
                  print ("Working")
            end
    end

    local function Upload ()

    uploadBinary ( image, "http://www.test1.bugs3.com/Corona.php", networkListener)
    end 




    myRoundedRect1:addEventListener( "tap", Upload )





    ?php
            $image_file = fopen($_POST['image_filename'], 'wb');

            $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['image_file']);
            $decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);

            fwrite($image_file, $decocedData);
            fclose($image_file);


    ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel... And why your wheel don't work?

Because you are using tostring on a table, tostring on a table always returns the table name, not its contents.

What you want to do, is anyway too complex to me describe here, but here is the wheel you was reinventing:

[CoronaLabs.com "how to upload image to server"](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/how-upload-image-server-multipartform-data)

:)